# Не открывает инлайн кнопку

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, lambda

[image: скриншот]

Когда нажимаю на инлайн кнопку выдаёт ошибку:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\Евгений\PycharmProjects\bot3\tg3.py", line 105, in <module>
    bot.polling ()
  File "C:\Users\Евгений\PycharmProjects\bot3\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 496, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Евгений\PycharmProjects\bot3\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 555, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Евгений\PycharmProjects\bot3\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 518, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\Евгений\PycharmProjects\bot3\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 117, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\Евгений\PycharmProjects\bot3\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 69, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Евгений\PycharmProjects\bot3\tg3.py", line 73, in inl
    nvk1.row(' Список тренеров', '➡️ Главное меню')
  File "C:\Users\Евгений\PycharmProjects\bot3\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\types.py", line 1043, in row
    return self.add(*args, row_width=self.max_row_keys)
  File "C:\Users\Евгений\PycharmProjects\bot3\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\types.py", line 1026, in add
    self.keyboard.append(button_array)
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'append'
```

```
import telebot
import const

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(const.TOKEN)


def menu():
    menu1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    but1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Новак Евгений', callback_data='novak')
    but2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Курникова Марина', callback_data='kurnikova')
    but3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Чоклу Вячеслав', callback_data='choklu')
    menu1.add(but1, but2, but3)
    return menu1


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    start = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
    start.row(' Адрес',' График работы')
    start.row(' Контакты',' Список тренеров')
    start.row(' Прайс лист')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вас приветсвует сеть фитнес центров - Fit4You!', reply_markup=start)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def next(message):
    if message.text == '➡️ Главное меню':
      start(message)

    elif message.text == ' Адрес':
        keybord = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
        keybord.row('➡️ Главное меню')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'г. Днепр, пр.Б.Хмельницкого 31Д', reply_markup=keybord)

    elif message.text == ' График работы':
        keybord = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
        keybord.row('➡️ Главное меню')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пн - Пт: 07:00-22:00\nСб, Вс: 09:00 - 20:00', reply_markup=keybord)

    elif message.text == ' Список тренеров':
        keybord = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
        keybord.row('➡️ Главное меню')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Фитнес:', reply_markup=menu())

    elif message.text == ' Прайс лист':
        keybord = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
        keybord.row('➡️ Главное меню')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'SUPER БЕЗЛИМ: Годовой абонемент - 3838 грн.\nУТРО+ВЫХОДНОЙ: Годовой абонемент - 2495 грн.\nБЕЗ ТРЕНЕРА: Годовой абонемент - 3375 грн.\nВЫХОДНОЙ: Годовой абонемент - 1000 грн.', reply_markup=keybord)

    elif message.text == ' Контакты':
        keybord = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        but1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Написать', url='https://t.me/boting', callback_data='b1')
        but2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Перейти на сайт', url='https://google.com', callback_data='b2')
        keybord.add(but1, but2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Мы находимся по адресу г. Днепр.\nпр. Б.Хмельницкого 11.Тел. +7459656559\nНаш Instagram: https://instagram.com/akk', reply_markup=keybord)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def inl(c):
    if c.data == 'trenera':
        trenera = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        but_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Новак', callback_data='novak')
        but_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Курникова', callback_data='kurnikova')
        but_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Чоклу', callback_data='choklu')
        trenera.add(but_1, but_2, but_3)
        bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id=c.message.chat.id, message_id=c.message.message_id, reply_markup=trenera)


    elif c.data == 'novak':
        nvk1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
        nvk1.row(' Список тренеров', '➡️ Главное меню')
        bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, 'Новак', reply_markup=nvk1)

        nvk101 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        but101 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(callback_data='nvk101')
        nvk101.add(but101)
        bot.send_photo(c.message.chat.id, 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAIOg2B3gctA6gJ-sLCJx5mZMnAHUBmUAAKktTEbEAe5SyQl4gr-twYIf0Kmoi4AAwEAAwIAA3gAAws2AQABHwQ', caption='ыраывраы', reply_markup=nvk101)

    elif c.data == 'kurnikova':
        kur1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
        kur1.row(' Список тренеров', '➡️ Главное меню')
        bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, 'Курникова', reply_markup=kur1)

        kur101 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup
        but101 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(callback_data='kur101')
        kur101.add(but101)
        bot.send_photo(c.message.chat.id, 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAIGYGBxz_YHmeb_6rom6y5WxFA8CUDuAAIHsjEbbWOQS9YPE8iFScJ1aOoymy4AAwEAAwIAA3gAA2QWBgABHgQ', caption='короу', reply_markup=kur101)

    elif c.data == 'choklu':
        cho1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
        cho1.row(' Список тренеров', '➡️ Главное меню')
        bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, 'Чоклу', reply_markup=cho1)

        cho101 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup
        but101 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(callback_data='cho101')
        cho101.add(but101)
        bot.send_photo(c.message.chat.id, 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAIGtWBx1P_8blC6DNaU-k3JpzpoLN1HAAIVsjEbbWOQS1LAcnc9X8V321VSoi4AAwEAAwIAA3gAA1z7AAIeBA', caption='віфвфів', reply_markup=cho101)





bot.polling ()
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Уберите аргументы в всех `types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()` потому-что когда пишите аргументы уточняйте машине какие именно например
   `types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard= True)`
   (В этом коде после дня перерыва можно и запутаться)
2. Так нельзя делать `kur1.row(' Список тренеров', '➡️ Главное меню')` чтобы это сработало надо сделать так:

```
but1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(' Список тренеров', callback_data='')
but2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('➡️ Главное меню', callback_data='')
```

3. В этих двух строчках большие ошибки

```
        kur101 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup
        but101 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(callback_data='kur101')
```

В первой нету скобок, а во второй нету текста(В кнопке он должен бить обязательно)

Эти 3 шага помогут вам решить вашу проблему